# R - Check for a word in interval in character vector

Tags: r

I have a sample code like this. Here, in the code `grepl("step")` checks for each line. Can I check it for the interval of q at once?

```
for(q in int[a]:int[a+1]){
if (grepl("step",x1[q])==F){
x2[q] <- gsub("ash","ashley",x1[q])}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ifelse` function, it can be applyed over a vector

```
x2 <- ifelse(grepl("step", x1[q]), x1[q], gsub("ash","ashley",x1[q]))
```

Where `q` is your interval. Notice that `x2` will be of the same length than your interval `q`

I hope it works for you!